# Doctrine2 Transient fields (like JPA)?

Tags: doctrine-orm

My problem is I can not find if it is somehow possible to specify a field to be transient.

I know that in java (JPA) you can specify it this way:

```
@Transient int transient;
```

There is a similar method in Doctrine2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each field on an entity that doctrine persists must be explicitly mapped (e.g., with annotations or YAML). If you don't want a field on an entity to be persisted then don't add any doctrine mapping for it:

```php
/** @Entity */
class MyPersistentClass
{
    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id; // will be persisted because it has a mapping

    private $name; // won't be persisted because it does not have a mapping
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I had misunderstood the way in which it takes by default the property name ( `/** @Column() */` must be specified)